# How to prove if a $\frac{c-xk}{a+xr}$ has a positive integer solution whe r,k,a and c are given?

Tags: abstract-algebra, diophantine-equations

How can i prove if a $\frac{c-xk}{a+xr}$ has a positive integer solution when r,c,a and k are given ? For example, $\frac{115-11x}{2+13x}$ has a solution in positive integer  ranging 2..3, while $\frac{109-10x}{10+13x}$ has no integer solution.Something like proving a Diophantine equation has an integer solution.

Could someone illustrate with proper examples please?

Comment: What do you mean with solution of a simple expression?

Comment: You've written two expressions, not two equations.  An expression can be simplified, but not "solved".

Comment: OP used a short form, like $x^2$ for a norm parabola $y = x^2$. This interpretation fits the Diophantine equations tag and the statements about the examples and their solutions.

Comment: Equation (c-xk)/(r+xk) may or may not have a solution in integer where c,k and r are given. I am actually stack in proving(not solving)  the condition necessary for the two instances.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Reformulation as solution of a quadratic Diophantine equation:**

We have
$$
y = \frac{c - k x}{a+r x} \iff \\
(a+r x) y =c -kx \iff \\
r xy + kx + ay = c \quad (*)
$$
assuming $r, k, a, c$ are integers, this is a special case of the quadratic Diophantine equation:
$$
A x^2 + B xy + C y^2 + Dx + E y + F = 0
$$
Your example with solutions 
$$
y = \frac{115-11x}{2+13x} \iff \\
13xy+11x+2y-115 = 0
$$
has $A=0$, $B=13$, $C=0$, $D=11$, $E=2$, $F=-115$ as coefficients.

**2. General solution:**

I put the coefficients in [Dario Alpern's Generic Two integer variable equation solver](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/JQUAD.HTM)  and got solutions and explanations.

You might try it as well, selecting the "Step-by-step" option for "Modes".

He also provides an explanation of the general method here:

- [Methods to solve $Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0$](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/METHODS.HTM)

**3. Solution for the special case (*):**

For our equation $(*)$ we got the [Simple Hyperbolic case $A=C=0; B\ne 0$](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/METHODS.HTM#SHyperb) explanation.

Before this step, the greatest common divisior of the non-constant coefficients $g = \gcd(r, k, a)$ is determined, and if $g \not\mid c$ then no integer solutions exist. For the example we have $g=1$ and solutions might exist.

Otherwise the equation is normalized by dividing both sides of the equation by $g$. (Instead of $r' = r/g$ etc, we are lazy and keep using $r$ etc). For the example this is not needed.

$$
r x y + k x + a y = c \iff \\
r^2 x y + r k x + r a y = r c \iff \\
r^2 x y + r k x + r a y + k a = k a + rc \iff \\
(r x + a) (r y + k) = k a + rc 
$$

If the RHS vanishes, one has two lines, one parallel to the $x$-axis, one parallel to the $y$-axis, as solutions over the real numbers.

Otherwise a hyperbola results as solution over the reals. This case we have for the example:
$$
(13 x + 11)(13 y + 2) = 1517
$$

Here the approach is then to find the divisors for the RHS
$$
d \mid ka + rc
$$
and checking the pairs 
$$
r x + a = d \quad r y + k = (k a + r c) / d \iff \\
x = \frac{d - a}{r} \quad y = \frac{(k a + r c) / d - k}{r}
$$
for integer solutions.

**4. Solution for the example with integer solutions:**

For the example we have
$$
d \mid 1517 = 37 \cdot 41 \iff \\
\lvert d \rvert \in \{ 1, 37, 41, 1517 \}
$$
and the solution candidates:
$$
x = \frac{d - 2}{13} \quad y = \frac{1517/d-11}{13}
$$
The positive solution exists for $d = 41$: 
$$
x = 3 \quad y = 2
$$

**5. Solution for the example without integer solutions:**

$$
y = \frac{109-10x}{10+13x} \iff \\
13 x y + 10 x + 10 y = 109 \iff \\
(13 x + 10)(13 y + 10) = 1517 = 37 \cdot 41
$$
Again we have $g=1$ and the divisors
$$
d \mid 1517 = 37 \cdot 41 \iff \\
\lvert d \rvert \in \{ 1, 37, 41, 1517 \}
$$
and here the solution candidates are
$$
x = \frac{d - 10}{13} \quad y = \frac{1517/d-10}{13}
$$
where no integer solution is among the candidates.

Comment: taking that the numbers involved are big can there be a time efficient approach.