# General method to numerically solve for the absolute maximum(s) of an irregular sinusoid

Tags: rational-functions

I am trying to find a strictly mathematical (i.e., not manual graphing or plugging) method to solve for the absolute (global) maximum value of an irregular sinusoid.

Given a rational function $f(x)$, i.e.,
$$f(x) = \frac{8480128-33x}{100x+63}$$
and a sinusoid transformed by the above function, i.e.,
$$r(x) = \cos(\pi f(x)) \cos(\pi x)$$
I am trying to numerically solve for the absolute maximum of $r(x)$. Right now, I have [plotted the function on Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/e1yx2x5udg) and manually checked for an intersection with the line $y=1$. I am also aware that I can iterate $x = 0, 1, ...$ at the peaks of $r(x)$ and checking $r(x)=1$ but **both of these methods are unsatisfactory** for $f(x)$ with large coefficients.

Setting $\cos\left(\pi \frac{8480128-33x}{100x+63}\right) \cos(\pi x)=1$, I do not know how to proceed algebraically or with calculus. I am looking for a way to deterministically find whether or not this function $r(x)$ will ever reach $y=1$ without doing too much manual work.

Comment: If we look at $8480128-33x=0 \implies x\approx 256973.6$ then $x= 256974$ should be give a result  $\approx 0.9999999999985...$.

Comment: It seems there is a solution at $x=139$.

Comment: You can be a lot more precise - see below. How general a case are you interested in for the rational function?

Answer (score 2):

The only way the product of two cosines (of real numbers) can ever be $1$ is if either both are equal to $1$ or both equal to $-1$. This simplifies things a lot!

If $\cos A = 1$, then $A=2k\pi$ for some integer $k$. So if $\cos \pi x = 1$ and $\cos \pi f(x) = 1$, we have $x=2k$ and $f(2k)$ is an even integer, say $2l$.

This means
$$8480128-66k = 2l(200k+63)$$

and it's (fairly) easy to check this has no integer solutions.

---

If $\cos A = -1$, then $A=2k\pi+\pi$ for some integer $k$. So if $\cos \pi x = -1$ and $\cos \pi f(x) = -1$, we have $x=2k+1$ and $f(2k+1)$ is an odd integer, say $2l+1$.

Substituting again, this is
$$8480128-66k-33 = (100(2k+1)+63)(2l+1)$$

which has the unique integer solution $k=69$, $l=303$, giving the unique maximum at $x=139$.

Answer (score 1):

One way to proceed can be find for $x$ real such that

$$8480128-33x=0 \implies x\approx 256973.6$$

therefore for $x=256974$ we obtain a value very close at $1$, that is

$$\cos\left(\pi \frac{8480128-33x}{100x+63}\right) \cos(\pi x)\approx 0.9999999999985...$$

Another strategy is look at integer solution for

$$f(x) = \frac{8480128-33x}{100x+63}$$

and, in this special case for example, we can find that $x=139$ is a solution with $f(139) = 607$ therefore

$$\cos(607\pi ) \cos(139\pi )=(-1)\cdot (-1)=1$$

---

**Idea for a general method**

Following the idea used in the particular example, more in general we can proceed as follows.

**1.** Look for solutions in $\mathbb Z$ of the rational equation $f(x)=n$ and we have three cases:

- $\exists n\in\mathbb Z$ even/odd for $x_0\in\mathbb Z$ even/odd $\implies r(x_0)=1$
- $\exists n\in\mathbb Z$ even/odd for $x_0\in\mathbb Z$ odd/even $\implies r(x_0)=-1$
- no solutions

To determine/check for an integer solution, we can refer, for example, to the general methods discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2829607/505767).

**2.** When no integer solutions exist, we can search for real solutions of $r(x_0)=0$ and then:

- for $\lceil x_0\rceil$ even $r(\lceil x_0\rceil) \approx 1$
- for $\lceil x_0\rceil$ odd $r(\lceil x_0\rceil) \approx -1$
- for $\lfloor x_0\rfloor$ even $r(\lfloor x_0\rfloor) \approx 1$
- for $\lfloor x_0\rfloor$ odd $r(\lfloor x_0\rfloor) \approx -1$

**3.** The previous method can be generalized searching for real solutions of $r(x_0)=2k$ and of $r(x_0)=2k+1$ with $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I considered that too, but finding integer solutions to the rational function appears to be NP-hard... I am trying to find a method that works for large coefficients in the rational, let's say $f(x)=\frac{716415207617514354551336164756670904340633322282478717948-37x}{100x+17}$

Comment: I think that at first we should look for integer solutions, we can use the method discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2829607/505767).

Comment: For very large coefficients I think we can use the first method I proposed to find very effectively close solutions.

Comment: Does the first method yield x=139 with the initial example? It seems to be a decent approximation but I am trying to get the true absolute max, not a super close estimate. Can it be tuned to find precise $x$? Is there another way to rewrite this problem to make it more feasible?

Comment: @user you have to be careful with the parity of an integer solution. If $x$ is odd and $f(x)$ is even (or vice-versa), the product of the two cosines will be $-1$.

Comment: @ChrisLewis Yes of course! indeed it works in this particular case, I'm not claiming that it is good in general. Of course we need to try with it, for a trivial solution.

Comment: @JW Sorry but I'm not aware for a general solution!